Finding an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space equipped with a hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Let $\mathcal{B} = \{b_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ be a basis of $V$ and let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be the matrix representing $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$, meaning that for all $v, w \in V$ with $v = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i b_i$ and $w = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \mu_i b_i$ we have:
$$
\langle v, w \rangle = \sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^n \lambda_i M_{i, j} \overline{\mu_j}
$$
Now, say we want to find a new basis $\mathcal{C}$ for $V$ which is orthonormal with respect to the hermitian inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. As far as I understand, we can do this in the following manner:
Since $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is sesquilinear, hermitian and positive-definite, $M$ will be a positive-definite hermitian matrix. According to the spectral theorem, such a matrix is unitarily diagonalizable with positive real eigenvalues.
Hence we have:
$$
M = U D U^*
$$
Equivalently:
$$
U^* M U = D
$$
where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with positive real entries. Now we can choose the following new basis: For $1 \leq k \leq n$, let $c_k = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n \overline{U_{i, k}} b_i$. Let $\tilde{c}_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k}}} c_k$. Let $\mathcal{C} = \{ \tilde{c}_k \}_{k = 1}^n$.
Now, we should check that this is really orthonormal. We have:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle \tilde{c}_k, \tilde{c}_k \rangle
& = & \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k}}} c_k, \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k}}} c_k \rangle \\
& = & \frac{1}{D_{k, k}} \langle c_k, c_k \rangle \\
& = & \frac{1}{D_{k, k}} \sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^n \overline{U_{i, k}} M_{i, j} U_{j, k} \\
& = & \frac{1}{D_{k, k}} \sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^n (U^*)_{k, i} M_{i, j} U_{j, k} \\
& = & \frac{1}{D_{k, k}} \left( U^* M U \right)_{k, k} \\
& = & \frac{1}{D_{k, k}} D_{k, k} \\
& = & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
For $k \neq l$ we have:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle \tilde{c}_k, \tilde{c}_l \rangle
& = & \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k}}} c_k, \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{l, l}}} c_l \rangle \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k} D_{l, l}}} \langle c_k, c_l \rangle \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k} D_{l, l}}} \sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^n \overline{U_{i, k}} M_{i, j} U_{j, l} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k} D_{l, l}}} \sum\limits_{i, j = 1}^n (U^*)_{k, i} M_{i, j} U_{j, l} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k} D_{l, l}}} \left( U^* M U \right)_{k, l} \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{D_{k, k} D_{l, l}}} D_{k, l} \\
& = & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$
My questions are:

Is the procedure I described here to obtain an orthonormal basis $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ actually correct?

How can this procedure be interpreted abstractly? Can it be phrased in terms of linear operators instead of matrices?

Can this procedure be simplified somehow?



Here is a more abstract way to phrase this procedure, answering question (2.):
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$ be hermitian inner products on $V$.
$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ gives us the following isomorphisms:
1.
$$
\alpha: V \overset{\sim}{\to} \overline{V}^*, v \mapsto \langle v, \cdot \rangle_1
$$
2.
$$
\beta: \operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes \overline{V}, \mathbb{C}) \overset{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(V, \overline{V}^*), f \mapsto \left[ v \mapsto [w \mapsto f(v \otimes w)] \right]
$$
3.
$$
\gamma: \operatorname{Hom}(V, \overline{V}^*) \overset{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{Hom}(V, V), f \mapsto \alpha^{-1} \circ f
$$
If $f \in \operatorname{Bil}(V \times \overline{V}, \mathbb{C})$ is any sesquilinear form and $\tilde{f} \in \operatorname{Hom}(V \otimes \overline{V}, \mathbb{C})$ is the corresponding map, we have for $v, w \in V$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle \gamma(\beta(\tilde{f}))(v), w \rangle_1
& = & \langle (\alpha^{-1} \circ \beta(\tilde{f}))(v), w \rangle_1 \\
& = & \langle \alpha^{-1}(\beta(\tilde{f})(v)), w \rangle_1 \\
& = & \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(\beta(\tilde{f})(v)))(w) \\
& = & \beta(\tilde{f})(v)(w) \\
& = & \tilde{f}(v \otimes w) \\
& = & f(v, w) \\
\end{array}
$$
Set $T = \gamma(\beta(\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2))$. We intend to show that $T$ is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$-self adjoint and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$-positive definite. Applying the above, we obtain $\langle T(v), w \rangle_1 = \langle v, w \rangle_2$ and $\langle v, T(w) \rangle_1 = \overline{\langle T(w), v \rangle_1} = \overline{\langle w, v \rangle_2} = \langle v, w \rangle_2$. Hence, $T$ is a $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$-self adjoint operator on $V$. We also have $\langle T(v), v \rangle_1 = \langle v, v \rangle_2 \geq 0$ for all $v \in V$ and $\langle T(v), v \rangle_1 = \langle v, v \rangle_2 > 0$ for $v \neq 0$. Hence $T$ is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$-positive definite.
By the spectral theorem, there exists a $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$-orthonormal basis $\{c_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. Additionally, the corresponding eigenvalues $\{\lambda_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ are positive and real. Define $\tilde{c}_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} c_i$ and $\mathcal{C} = \{\tilde{c}_i\}_{i = 1}^n$. Then we have:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle \tilde{c}_i, \tilde{c}_i \rangle_2
& = & \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} c_i, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} c_i \rangle_2 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \langle c_i, c_i \rangle_2 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \langle T(c_i), c_i \rangle_1 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\lambda_i} \langle \lambda_i c_i, c_i \rangle_1 \\
& = & \langle c_i, c_i \rangle_1 \\
& = & 1 \\
\end{array}
$$
and for $i \neq j$:
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\langle \tilde{c}_i, \tilde{c}_j \rangle_2
& = & \langle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}} c_i, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_j}} c_j \rangle_2 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} \langle c_i, c_j \rangle_2 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} \langle T(c_i), c_j \rangle_1 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} \langle \lambda_i c_i, c_j \rangle_1 \\
& = & \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda_i \lambda_j}} \lambda_i \langle c_i, c_j \rangle_1 \\
& = & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$
Thus, $\mathcal{C}$ is a $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$-orthonormal basis of $V$.
